# ssh returning different fingerprint over different ports

Tags: ssh

I am trying to run a script that connects to a ssh server over two different ports (one normal and one over a known non-default port). But the ssh server is given back two different fingerprints which breaks my script.

Is there a way to avoid this (having two different entries in 'known_hosts' for different ports)? Or the only way out is to talk to the admin?

PS: Nothing hacky - just trying to get Gerrit to run on my local desktop instead of a server.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem occurs when you have two different adapters - one working as NAT and other working as a normal adapter.

This happened to me when I was using ssh from two different ports on a virtual machine. The VM was configured with NAT and Bridged adapter.

When I tried to ssh on default port, NAT was being used, giving me a different fingerprint than when I trying to ssh via non-default port (for which bridged adapter was getting used).

HTH for those who run into the same problem...